# Java and .NET Streams Interoperability Through IKVM

Tags: c#, java, xml, stream, ikvm

In my current project I use IKVM to cross-compile several Java libraries that deal with various aspects of XML. These libraries are then integrated with several .NET libraries and my mainline code. Everything works fine, but I suspect that there are several inefficiencies, especially in the area of stream-based data access.

Many of the Java libraries can accept streaming SAX classes or other streaming objects such as OutputStream, etc. In some cases I can wrap the appropriate Java class in a coorisponding .NET subclass to bridge the gap and provide seamless streaming between the two languages. For example, creating a class that derives from both the .NET MemoryStream and the Java OutputStream. In most cases however, the interface is challenging and I am left passing whole strings around - even though I have streams available on the .NET side and the Java side accepts (different) stream classes (and vice versa).

In general my question is if anyone has encountered similar problems passing data to/from IKVM compiled libraries using streams and how were they solved or mitigated? Do any third-party solutions exist to help bridge this gap? For example, code that provides Java SAX wrappers for .NET XmlReader and/or XmlWriter would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some bridging classes for this kind of thing in [Saxon](https://github.com/fidothe/saxon-he). It's open source, so you can reuse anything you find useful. Though I don't guarantee that they're complete and correct if you use them in ways other than the way Saxon uses them.

[DotNetInputStream](https://github.com/fidothe/saxon-he/blob/master/bj/net/sf/saxon/dotnet/DotNetInputStream.java) maps a .NET stream to a Java InputStream.

[DotNetOutputStream](https://github.com/fidothe/saxon-he/blob/master/bj/net/sf/saxon/dotnet/DotNetOutputStream.java) maps a .NET stream to a Java OutputStream.

[DotNetReader](https://github.com/fidothe/saxon-he/blob/master/bj/net/sf/saxon/dotnet/DotNetReader.java) maps a .NET TextReader to a Java Reader.

[DotNetWriter](https://github.com/fidothe/saxon-he/blob/master/bj/net/sf/saxon/dotnet/DotNetWriter.java) maps a .NET TextWriter to a Java Writer.

For XML streams, Saxon has its own internal push/pull interfaces (Receiver and PullProvider respectively), and there are classes that map both of these to/from the corresponding Java and .NET interfaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Saxon is one of the "Java libraries that deal with various aspects of XML" that I'm including, so ripping out the interface classes shouldn't be too tough.